# detect edge using python and Opencv2

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have this picture below , i want to separate it to tow part, so i can work independently with every part alone , i added those black dots to make my algo detect the dots and separate the part but it's detect all the elements of paper it' doesn't work  as i expected, i do not know the reason why

this is my code

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('18936-model-1.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (23, 23), 0)
cv2.imshow("blurred", blurred)
canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 30, 30)
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(canny.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
print(f"Contours in the image, %d" % (len(cnts)))
shape = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(shape, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imwrite('{}.png'.format('sunflower'), shape)
cv2.imshow("Edges", shape)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

this is the original image

[image]

this is how i want separate my picture

[image]

this is what i get

[image]

Comment: Post your original, unprocessed image.

Comment: i'am new i could not post the image in the same post  you should click the link unfortunately

Comment: Both images are annotated, we can't work with that, we need the original image that you haven't posted yet. Just edit your question and add the image.

Comment: @stateMachine  sorry i add it

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/split-a-multiple-choice-answer-sheet/8898

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution. The idea is just to use the horizontal line to split the images. However, we don't really need the full image. The line extends along all the width, so I just extract a couple of first columns, reduced them to a column and search the position (or indices) where the maximum intensity value is present.

After I have this info, I can split the original image along that reference. Let's see the code:

```
# Imports
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "xIe0M.jpg"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)

# To grayscale:
grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Otsu Threshold:
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Apply thinning:
binaryImage = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(binaryImage, None, 1)

# Show the image:
showImage("binaryImage", binaryImage)

# Get image dimensions:
(imageHeight, imageWidth) = binaryImage.shape[:2]

# Get ROIs:
roiHeight = imageHeight
roiWidth = int(0.01 * imageWidth)

# Store ROIs here:
verticalCropPoints = []

# Crop first and last row:
horizontalMargin = 2
binaryImage = binaryImage[0:imageHeight, horizontalMargin:imageWidth - horizontalMargin]

# Extract left and right ROIs:
# Set Cropping dimensions:
xStart = clamp((imageWidth - roiWidth), 0, imageWidth)
xEnd = roiWidth
yStart = 0
yEnd = roiHeight

# Crop the ROI:
currentRoi = binaryImage[yStart:yEnd, xStart:xStart + xEnd]

# Image reduction to a column:
reducedImage = cv2.reduce(currentRoi, 1, cv2.REDUCE_MAX)
```

The first step involves converting the image to binary, then apply a thinning. This operation will normalize the horizontal width to one pixel. I don't really need more than one pixel for the horizontal line. This is the result so far:

[image]

It is very subtle, but this is the ROI (`1%` of the original width) reduced to just one column. Let's find where the maximum value is present (you can actually see a faint white pixel on the past image):

```
# Get indices of maximum values:
maxIndexCol = np.nonzero(reducedImage)

# Store all the indices here:
verticalCropPoints = np.append(verticalCropPoints, maxIndexCol[0])
```

Now I have the vertical position of the horizontal line. Let's crop based on this info. The approach is implemented with a loop that crops iteratively until the last vertical coordinate is reached:

```
# Crop image:
cropImage = True
cropCounter = len(verticalCropPoints)

# Loop variables:
xStart = 0
xEnd = imageWidth
yPast = 0
j = 0

while cropImage:

    if j < cropCounter:
        y = int(verticalCropPoints[j])
        yStart = yPast
        yEnd = y
        yPast = y
    else:
        yStart = yPast
        yEnd = imageHeight
        cropImage = False

    currentCrop = inputImage[yStart:yEnd, xStart:xStart + xEnd]
    cv2.imshow("currentCrop", currentCrop)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    # Increment step counter:
    j += 1
```

These are the results (scaled for the post, open them in new tabs to see them at full resolution):

[image]
[image]

Let's check out how the algorithm scales to more than one horizontal line. This is a modification of your original image, with two horizontal lines:

[image]

Which yields these individual images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

There's an auxiliary function I use, to clamp a number to a valid range:

```
# Clamps an integer to a valid range:
def clamp(val, minval, maxval):
    if val < minval: return minval
    if val > maxval: return maxval
    return val
```

You will also need **OpenCV's extended image processing** module in order to skeletonize/thin the image.

Comment: @stateMachine for some reason I am unable to see any of the result images. Don't know if it is a problem at my end. As always well written post

Comment: @JeruLuke Thanks. Do you mean you have problems seeing the posted images? I use imgur.com to host the files and then embedded them directly in the post. I'm seeing them right now. Can you open them in a new tab? Maybe there's a problem with the external linking, but so far the images seem to be displayed correctly.

Comment: @stateMachine Yes I'm able to see it now :)

Comment: @stateMachine your solution work excellent on blank paper i want to ask you that if the paper  filled up with the name   id and student answer .. , is the value of maximum intensity value  will change  ??